# Unicode in folder path

Tags: python, character-encoding

I'm stuck with python and unicode/character encoding (Python 2.7) when it comes to folder paths.

I build a path from single parts, created by my script:

```
>>> parts = {u'first':var_a, u'second':var_b, u'third':var_c}
>>> parts
{u'second': u'\xe4\xfc\xf6\xdf', u'third': u'1120_21_22', u'first': u'0222'}
```

...followed by:

```
>>> path = os.path.join('test', parts[u'first'], parts[u'second'], parts[u'third'])
>>> path
u'test\\0222\\\xe4\xfc\xf6\xdf\\1120_21_22'
```

There is no problem with printing that:

```
>>> print path
test\0222\äüöß\1120_21_22
```

And it's also valid:

```
>>> os.path.isdir(path)
True
```

**But i can't open it:**

```
>>> subprocess.Popen(u'explorer "' + path + u'"')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 679, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 896, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 20-23: ordinal not in range(128)
```

This happens only with special-chars in the path. What kind of encoding/decoding needs to be done to make the `subprocess`-call work?

Answer (score 1):

This is a known bug in Python. You're unable to specify the encoding to subprocess.Popen: https://bugs.python.org/issue6135

That issue also has a workaround:

```
my_env = os.environ
my_env['PYTHONIOENCODING'] = 'utf-8'
subprocess.Popen(u'explorer "' + path + u'"', env=my_env)
```

Comment: Thank you for this tip! But... the workaround didn't solve the issue for me, i still get the same error. I'm actually starting the `subprocess` with a wxpython button klick - does that matter?